# MySQL timestamp only on create

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I use timestamp on MySQL 5.x (with PHP) to remember event times. During development I had to update the table with a query that changes something in all columns. The timestamp was then reset to current time.

How can I make timestamp change only on inserts and not on updates or replace?

Comment: A late answer for others who may Google this: if you use a TIMESTAMP when you do manuals edits in your database; or if you have multiple TIMESTAMP columns and do not want to touch all of them; the MySQL manual says to assign the column to itself. You explicitly set the column to its current value (ie. "updated_on = updated_on"), so that it is not changed by the UPDATE.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[Here's all you need to know](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html). In short, though, I think this should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
CHANGE `mydatefield` `mydatefield`
TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Thanks! In here "NOT NULL" part is not required I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Very good documentation here [for time-stamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html).

Comment: I may be missing something but my table is (and was) defined this way but still the dates changed. From mysql explain: 'pur_time', 'timestamp', 'NO', '', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', ''

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [default value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) for that field and not include it in the insert or update query.