# MySQL - Static timestamp needed for new database record

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table where I need to store the TIMESTAMP from when the row was created (registration TIMESTAMP).  How do I create a field that is only TIMESTAMPed when it is created, and never when the row is updated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql timestamp only on create](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817396/mysql-timestamp-only-on-create)

Answer (score 1):

when you create the table you put the default value of the column to be current_timestamp(). Somewhere along these lines.

```
create table `x` (
  id integer auto_increment not null, 
  timestamp TIMESTAMP default current_timestamp
  data CHAR(100)
);
```

and you don't set the field on insert/updates.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create a new row simply add the TIMESTAMP to it. ALternatively you make it the default

```
CREATE TABLE your_table(name VARCHAR32, your_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the MySQL INSERT statement, I passed a value of NOW() which records the current time.