# Default Value for Date in SQL

Tags: mysql

If i didnt get value for created_date it throws mysql errror.
How To solve this problem?

```
var query1 = "INSERT INTO prospect_group(
    group_name,status_id,created_date,  
    is_eligible,mom_active_fromdt,
    mom_is_savings_discussed,
    is_full_attendence,is_internal_loan) VALUES
    ('"+groupNameArray[0]+"', '"
       +groupNameArray[14]+"', '"
       +groupNameArray[1]+"', '"
       +groupNameArray[15]+"','"
       +groupNameArray[7]+"','"
       +groupNameArray[8]+"','"
       +groupNameArray[9]+"','"
       +groupNameArray[10]+"'  )";
```

Comment: @xdazz Please either revert your edit or make it better. The original one is much more readable than the current one.

Comment: Hi, I belive this is answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column

Comment: Do you mean groupNameArray[1] is null? If so, what do you want to insert instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SYSDATE() or NOW()

Answer (score 1):

Setting `created_date` field default value to *Null*

or

Use `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` in the JDBC connection

example:

```
jdbc:mysql://192.168.6.1/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Reference:
[handling DATETIME values 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (setting the default value for the created_date field):
[MySQL timestamp only on create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817396/mysql-timestamp-only-on-create)

Comment: Actually i am not able to give default value.I am working in application so it needs some reliable data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add NULL set default value to NULL for created_date column and make sure that while  you insert into table you'll have either date or null.

Comment: I had similar problem by assigning default value to null it's solved. Try executing query >> ALTER TABLE `cp_users`
CHANGE COLUMN `created_date` `created_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL;